# How can i iterate through a python dict and reach easily the leaves?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, parallel-processing, parent-child

I am trying to iterate a graph-dict object and reach every time the leave nodes, and i want to do it for different level of depth of the graph (if the leaves are in a deeper level )

```
{'Node': [0, 0, 0],
 'children': [{'Node': [1, 0, 0],
   'children': [{'Node': [2, 0, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [1, 1, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [1, 0, 1], 'children': []}]},
  {'Node': [0, 1, 0],
   'children': [{'Node': [1, 1, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 2, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 1, 1], 'children': []}]},
  {'Node': [0, 0, 1],
   'children': [{'Node': [1, 0, 1], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 1, 1], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 0, 2], 'children': []}]}]}
```

In particular i want to do something with this leaves nodes,(i have a function that can add  other children) but with a parallel logic, using libraries like multiprocessing or joblib exc..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Are you asking, how you can get the value of a 'Node' and add to it something to it?

Comment: I'm asking how to get the values of leaf nodes (nodes that are at the deeper level) and do some functions on them (in a parallel logic () if it's possible) in a kind of recursive way (if it's possible)

Comment: Like for each leaf node a Pool.map function that generates its childrens and they'll be attached to children lists of each leaf node (the new children will become new leaf nodes and so on..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion in this case.
Below is a sample code.

```py
graph={'Node': [0, 0, 0],
 'children': [{'Node': [1, 0, 0],
   'children': [{'Node': [2, 0, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [1, 1, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [1, 0, 1], 'children': []}]},
  {'Node': [0, 1, 0],
   'children': [{'Node': [1, 1, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 2, 0], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 1, 1], 'children': []}]},
  {'Node': [0, 0, 1],
   'children': [{'Node': [1, 0, 1], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 1, 1], 'children': []},
    {'Node': [0, 0, 2], 'children': []}]}]}

def collect_children(nodes):
  children=[]
  for node in nodes:
    if len(node['children'])!=0:
      children+=node['children']
  return children

def get_leaves(nodes, depth):
  if depth==0:
    return []
  elif depth==1:
    return collect_children(nodes)
  else:
    return get_leaves(collect_children(nodes),depth-1)

print(get_leaves([graph],2))
```

Comment: Is it possible in your opinion to add other children to the leaf nodes in a parallel environment?